# how to redirect from a utility function in remix run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, remix.run

I am using Remix-run and i want to redirect to my login page from a auth utility function. but it doesnt work. here is a similar function to my authentication utility method

```js
import { redirect } from 'remix';

 async function authenticate(request){
  try{
    const user = await rpc.getUser(request);
    return user
  } catch(e){
   console.log(e) // logs error when rpc fails
   if(e.response.status === 401){
    return redirect('/login')
   }
   return redirect('/500')
  }
 }
```

`//component.jsx`

```js
import {useLoaderData } from 'remix';

export async function loader({ request }) {
  const user = await auth.authenticate(request);
  return { user };
}

export default function Admin(){
 const { user } = useLoaderData();
  return <h1>{user.name}</h1>
}
```

if the auth rpc fails i get the error in the logs. but redirect never happens.
If i move `redirect` part to my loader function it works as expected. its not only working inside the utility function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After digging in the docs and remix jokes app demo. i found that you need to throw a redirect from any other function other than loaders/actions to do redirects. you can also throw Http response if wanted.

```js
import { redirect } from 'remix';

 async function authenticate(request){
  try{
    const user = await rpc.getUser(request);
    return user
  } catch(e){
   if(e.response.status === 401){
    throw redirect('/login')
   }
   throw redirect('/500')
  }
 }
```