# How to use redirect from @remix-run/node

Tags: remix.run

I'm attempting to create a simple redirect from the root path `/` to `/welcome` using `redirect` from `@remix-run/node`.

The directory structure is:

```
routes/
├── index.tsx
└── welcome/
    └── index.tsx
```

This approach works fine:

```
import Welcome from '~/routes/welcome/index'
export default <Welcome />
```

I was hoping for this to work:

```
import { redirect } from '@remix-run/node'
export default () => redirect('/welcome')
```

However that results in `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Response]).`

Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528730/how-to-redirect-from-a-utility-function-in-remix-run) suggest using `throw redirect` however that doesn't seem to work in this case.

The Remix [documentation](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#action) infers the use of the `action` function, however this seems to only return the default component and doesn't run the action:

```
import { redirect } from '@remix-run/node'
export function action() {
  return redirect('/welcome')
}
export default () => null
```

I have a good fallback but curious to know if `redirect` can be used in this fashion.

Stackblitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-jlmr12?file=app/routes/index.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirects can only be made from loaders and actions since these are server functions. The default export is only used for the UI.

```js
// index.tsx
export const loader = () => redirect('/welcome')
```